# OpenCV Java RGB or HSV?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to decipher some code that I want to use but the code requires calibration but I am confused whether it uses HSV or RGB? 
Sorry for the noob question but I am not too familiar with OpenCV. 
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(matOriginal,matHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);         
        Core.inRange(matHSV, LOWER_BOUNDS, UPPER_BOUNDS, matThresh);
        Imgproc.findContours(matThresh, contours, matHeirarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
        Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

I know I have to change the lower and upper bounds but should I use RGB values or HSV values? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(matOriginal,matHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

This line assure that the values of `matHSV` are in HSV color system. Thus means from now any operation on `matHSV` should be done considering all the values are in HSV. So, in this line :

```
Core.inRange(matHSV, LOWER_BOUNDS, UPPER_BOUNDS, matThresh);
```

`LOWER_BOUNDS` and `UPPER_BOUNDS` should be HSV values.

Comment: The upper and lower bounds should now be the values in H-S-V order? Just checking because I know that it is flipped for RGB

Comment: Yes H-S-V order. For RGB, it is not flipped actually. It is BGR which is a totally diffrent color system from RGB (They are same but flipped in practical but theoretically they are different systems)

Comment: Actually your statement about bgr seems wrong... ;D See e.g. [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/)

Comment: @Miki hhhh Nice article.. anyway it does not contradict with my comment that BGR is other format than RGB. I see naming RGB as a flipped BGR is like naming HSV as a F(B,G,R) of the BGR format :D